# Как выбрать данные из двух не связанных таблиц? Django ORM + MySQL

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django, django-orm

Подключаюсь с помощью Django ORM к удаленной базе данных MySQL. После выполнения команды

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

добавил в models.py такие классы:

```
class CustomerEquipment(models.Model):
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    dateofсheck = models.DateField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = models.IntegerField()
    state_timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    department_equipment = models.IntegerField()
    state_type = models.IntegerField()
    manufacture = models.CharField(max_length=45)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'customer_equipment'


class LogCustomerEquipment(models.Model):
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = models.IntegerField()
    state_timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    department = models.IntegerField()
    state_type = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'log_customer_equipment'
```

Нужно сделать выборку всех уникальных **serial_number** из таблицы **LogCustomerEquipment** за определенный период и др. указанными фильтрами:

```
list_equipments = LogCustomerEquipment.objects.using('portal').filter(Q(state_type=10) & Q(state_timestamp__gte='2019-12-01 00:00:00') & Q(state_timestamp__lte='2019-12-01 23:59:59') & Q(department=19))
```

После этого, требуется выбрать из таблицы **CustomerEquipment** по каждому найденному **serial_number** - расширенные данные (*name*, *address*, *manufacture* и пр.).

Как это сделать? Как объединить запросы? Как их оптимизировать?

*serial_number в обоих таблицах - одинаковые.
Стоит также учитывать, что указанная удаленная база данных используется в других приложениях. Не только мной. Не хочется менять структуру базы данных, поскольку можно что-то сломать у других программ/пользователей.*

Comment: не проще объединить таблицы  с помощью ForeignKey ?

Comment: @user355827 как это лучше сделать в моем случае? Стоит учитывать, что указанная удаленная база данных используется в других приложениях. Не только мной. Не хочется менять структуру базы данных, чтобы ничего не сломать у других программ и пользователей.

Comment: serial_number уникальные?

Comment: @user355827 - нет, могут встречаться не уникальные в обоих таблицах. Но из LogCustomerEquipment нужно выбирать только уникальные serial_number.

Comment: `LogCustomerEquipment` и `CustomerEquipment` - они же на одном сервере? составьте сперва ОДИН запрос на основании ДВУХ таблиц, получающий сразу ВСЕ данные - а уж потом превращайте его в код для фреймворка.

Comment: @Akina верно, они на одном сервере. Можете привести пример?

Answer (score 2):

В формате SQL это будет что-то вроде

```sql
SELECT lce.*, ce.*  /* заменить на список нужных полей */
FROM LogCustomerEquipment lce
JOIN CustomerEquipment ce ON lce.equipment_id = ce.id
WHERE /* все условия отбора */
      lce.state_type=10
  AND lce.state_timestamp__gte='2019-12-01 00:00:00'
  AND lce.state_timestamp__lte='2019-12-01 23:59:59'
  AND lce.department=19
```

или, если такое проще преобразовывать для фреймворка

```sql
SELECT lce.*, ce.*  /* заменить на список нужных полей */
FROM LogCustomerEquipment lce, CustomerEquipment ce 
WHERE lce.equipment_id = ce.id
      /* и теперь все условия отбора */
  AND lce.state_type=10
  AND lce.state_timestamp__gte='2019-12-01 00:00:00'
  AND lce.state_timestamp__lte='2019-12-01 23:59:59'
  AND lce.department=19
```